# how to deal with special characters in fusion charts while making xml through php

Tags: javascript, php, xml, fusioncharts

I am using fusion charts, and getting xml of fusion charts through ajax. On server side I am using php to make xml. 
I am using htmlentities function like this

```
$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES , 'UTF-8');
```

to encode special characters and getting this kind of xml

```
<dataset seriesName='le fran&ccedil;ais'>
```

for le français.

But is does not show in fusion chart. Plz tell me the correct way to do it.

Comment: What does it show instead?

Comment: Also, how is the initial value of name created? Is it being read from a database, sent through an html page or just created in the php file itself?

Comment: Read the documentation http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/advanced/special-chars/SpPunctuation.html

Comment: @J. Rahmati, I am getting the name (that contains special chars) from database and then using it in creating xml that is being used in fusion charts. And the name that contains special chars is something like this **le français**

Answer (score 1):

I just made a PHP file with the lines below and save it as an ANSI encoded file:

```
$name = 'le français';
$name = htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES);
echo $name;
```

This just gave me the result you were expecting:

```
le fran&ccedil;ais
```

Seems the special charcter just gets ignored when using UTF-8 as encoding:

```
htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks rahmati , but this is not solving my problem. Actually I am getting the same output as you are getting and making the xml like this  '<chart numberPrefix='$' rotateValues='1'>
    <set label='J' toolText='January' value='434' />
    <set label='F' toolText='February' value='376' />
     <set label='le fran&ccedil;ais' toolText='February' value='376' />
</chart>'. Value J and F show in chart properly but the third doesnt show at all in chart. I hope now u got my point.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I misunderstood your question. From what I understand from N Bhargavs link is that you don't have to convert special characters to this kind of markup. Have you tried outputting the contents in plain php instead of fusionchart to check if there isn't anything wrong with the character encoding?